# How to sort entity model by column name of display model in C# .NET Core using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, .net-core, expression

I have a page that displays all users in the table.

The front end uses a class that is different from the database model.

```
public class UserDetailsViewDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

When the user chooses to sort by Role, the frontend sends `string SortColum = "Role"`. I can map that to any other property but in this case, I need that to be `User.UserRoles.FirstOrDefault().Role.Name`

Query:

```
var users = Context.Users
                   .Include(user => user.UserRoles)
                       .ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role)
                   .ApplySort(string ParameterName)
                   .ToList();
```

The problem is: I must return a list of Users from the repository to a business layer of application where I do mapping to `UserDetailsViewDto`.

These are the extension methods I use to sort data:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplySort<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, QueryResource query)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.SortColumn))
        return source;

    return source.OrderBy(query.SortColumn, query.SortDirection == "desc");
}

public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string orderByProperty, bool desc)
{
    string command = desc ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";

    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(orderByProperty, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
    var resultExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), command, new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));

    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExpression);
}
```

User is just an example, I have many other pages with a similar problem. How to solve this?

Is sending `IQueryable` from a repository and using `ProjectTo()` only solution?

Thanks.

Comment: This is what I call overthinking. LinQ has already OrderBy methods

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Yes, but not by property name and mapping that property to another model property... Do you have any idea of how I can do this your way?

Comment: I think your problem is from the architecture, I should see the arch to answer you. But what I do is order the view, not the data.

Comment: Thanks, arch is not that complex:
Controller -> Service (to view data) -> Repository (returns entity data, sort is here)-> DB.
So you suggest I should return IQuerable from the repository and do order in the Service where I map entity data to view data?

Comment: Why would you order the data at repository level if you want to order the data in the view? I would order the data in the view without going to the server, at clientside. If not possible, at controller. That's the principle of MVC. You are working with MVC but you are not using it.

Comment: The main reason is pagination. I have tables with 40k+ rows. I must first do filter and sort data and after that pagination.

Comment: I understand, but you can separate the "pagination" logic from the "view" logic. You only need the data to show for x page, the number of total pages and the current page. You shouldnt get 40k to show 20 for pagination

Comment: There is nothing in your example code that specifies pagination. If you want a complete answer - you need to ask a complete question. Additionally, @LeandroBardelli is correct. Do your sorting at the DTO level - if you have to sort and paginate at the database level, do it in your IQueryable.

Comment: I don't need compete answer, I just need what I specified and that is how to sort data by property exposed to the client. Is there a way to somehow map parameter expression or similar? Post your answer if you can help. Select 20 and then sort them is clearly not a solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't understand why  "Select 20 and then sort them is clearly not a solution" if the user sort them in the view. If not, the solution is "sort them, select 20 and sort them again". In any case you never get 40k and sort them every time, you work with the data you will show. If the sort implies a primary sorting, not a secondary, you have to go to the database mandatory and then sort and select 20.